# When requiring modules, should the name be a string, symbol, or keyword?

Tags: common-lisp

What is the difference between the following?

```
(require "asdf")  ; String.
(require 'asdf)   ; Symbol.
(require :asdf)   ; Keyword.
```

Which should I use when requiring modules?

Comment: Using keywords will create keywords in the Lisp image, so this will "pollute" the keywords namespace. They can pop-up in completion suggestions even if they are not useful anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The argument of `require` is a [string designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator) which is

> a designator for a string; that is, an object that denotes a string and that is one of: a character (denoting a singleton string that has the character as its only element), a symbol (denoting the string that is its name), or a string (denoting itself).

So any of the above will work.  *However*, [`require`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_provid.htm#require) is defined to make comparisons between module names using `string=`, which means that *case matters*.  So this means that `(require 'asdf)` is the same as `(require :ASDF)` is the same as `(require "ASDF")` but is *not* the same as `(require "asdf")`.  (In fact, ASDF adds both `"asdf"` and `"ASDF"` to `*modules*` so both will work.)

Personally, I use keyword symbols, so `(require :asdf)`, `(provide :spotbat)`, which means `*modules*` always ends up with upper-case strings.

---

I find the decision to use `string=` to compare module names a bit annoying, but it is what it is now, and it is also compatible with various other conventions: package names, for instance, are case sensitive.  And in theory it would allow, for instance, a case sensitive lowercase-preferred language to exist alongside CL in the same image (`(find-package "cl")` could be the package that exported all its symbols).

Comment: Is `(require :asdf)` the same as `(require :ASDF)`?

Comment: @Flux: yes, because `(eq :asdf :ASDF)` (and also `(eq :asdf :aSdF)`).

Comment: According to ASDF's documentation: "The recommended way to load ASDF is via: `(require "asdf")`".

Comment: In CLISP, `(require :asdf)` gives an error, whereas `(require "asdf")` succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to ASDF.

The recommended way to load ASDF is by using `(require "asdf")` (i.e. using a lowercase string). According to the [ASDF manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Loading-ASDF), section 3 ("Loading ASDF"):

> The recommended way to load ASDF is via:
>
> `(require "asdf")`

The footnote says:

> NB: all implementations except GNU CLISP also accept `(require "ASDF")`, `(require 'asdf)` and `(require :asdf)`. For portability’s sake, you should use `(require "asdf")`.